# Subtracting variables in a loop

Tags: for-loop, ksh

I've 3 lines and I would like to check the status of each line for a specific variable i.e `OFF`.

So basically I need to loop this 3 lines and exit the loop when all 3 lines variable status are `OFF` or else just loop for ever.
 I've tried the while true do loop but to no avail. Any help or advise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will some other prog update the lines?  Do you want something like `while [ $(grep -c "OFF" "${file}") -ne 3 ]; do sleep 60; done` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be done by searching on each line variable OFF and counting set one variable to count=0 and iff line ~/OFF/ count++ , which language do you use.?

Comment: I use ksh / bash / awk

Comment: what's the format of your lines , you can use awk -F"sep" '{if($x ~/OFF/) print $0}'

Comment: if you want to check the whole line put awk -F"sep" '{if($0 ~/OFF/) print $0}'  file    , sep can be , or ; or |